# How do I use the throwing knives?

Tags: ps4, far-cry-4

I've just started playing FarCry 4, and have picked up some **throwing knives** and an **assault rifle**.

When I initially picked up the knives, I think a tutorial displayed briefly on the bottom of the screen, but I was in the middle of a gun fight and wasn't able to see what it said.

I've been trying to figure out how to use the throwing knives, but can't find anything about them in the game's help.  I see that **I have access to a weapon wheel by pressing** <kbd>**L1**</kbd>, however when I select the knives the assault rifle remains equipped.

That makes me think that both weapons can be active at the same time, so how do I actually throw a knife?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a controller layout or keybind settings ingame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use <kbd>**R1**</kbd> to throw a knife after selecting it from the <kbd>**L1**</kbd> wheel.

Comment: To add a little more, you always have a weapon and a thrown object selected separately. One button will fire your primary weapon which is visible in your hands while another will throw whatever you have selected: knives, bait, grenade, etc.

Comment: For PC users, throwing knives function as all throwables (eg. grenades). Equip with `mouse wheel` or numbers. Middle click (maybe even `G`) to throw.